# Merge two multidimensional arrays but preserve only associative keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to merge two arrays recursively, leaving associative keys in place, but replace other. I tried using `is_numeric()` for key checking, but keys '10' and '11' are replaced.

Sample arrays:

Array1:

```
$arr1['assoc']='foobar';
$arr1[]='test index';
$arr1[][]=array(3,4);
$arr1['10']['test10'][]=array(0,1);
$arr1['11']['test11']=45;
$arr1['multiarray'][]=array(0,1);
```

Array2:

```
$arr2[]=1;
$arr2[][]=2;
$arr2['assoc']='test passed';
$arr2['10']['test10'][]=array(0,2);
$arr2['11']['test11']=array(4,5);
$arr2['multiarray'][]=array(0,2);
```

How to merge them to get this (with a general function):

```
array(
    'assoc' => 'test passed',
    0 => 'test index',
    1 => array(
        0 => array(
            0 => 3,
            1 => 4,
        ),
    ),
    10 => array(
        'test10' => array (
            0 => array(
                0 => 0,
                1 => 1,
            ),
            1 => array(
                0 => 0,
                1 => 2,
            ),
        ),
    ),
    11 => array(
        'test11' => array (
            1 => 4,
            2 => 5,
        ),
    ),
    'multiarray' => array(
        0 => array(
            0 => 0,
            1 => 1,
        ),
        1 => array(
            0 => 0,
            0 => 2,
        ),
    ),
    2 => 1,
    3 => array(
        0 => 2,
    ),
)
```

Preserving keys' order is not important.

## [Edit] Solution:

```
function array_max_index_key($arr) {
    $prev = -1;
    if(is_array($arr)) {
        $keys = array_keys($arr);
        foreach($keys as $k => $key) {
            if(is_numeric($key)) {
                if($key == $prev+1) {
                    $prev=$key;
                } else break;
            }
        }
    }
    return $prev;
}

function justfortesting($a1, $a2) {
    $res=$a1;
    $max_key=array_max_index_key($res);
    if(is_array($a1)) {
        foreach ($a2 as $k => $v) {
            if(is_numeric($k) && $k<=$max_key) {
                $max_key++;
                $res[$max_key]=$v;
            } elseif (is_array($v)) {
                $res[$k]=justfortesting($a1[$k], $v);
            } else {
                $res[$k]=$v;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $res=$a2;
    }
    return $res;
}

$arr3=justfortesting($arr1, $arr2);
```

Comment: *All* keys are associative. The only thing that could be said is if keys are *numerically continuous*, but that's pretty tough if you have valid numeric non-continuous keys in there as well. Isn't there a better approach to whatever you're trying to do here?

Comment: have you tried type casting the key to (int) then checking with is_int in your loop?

Comment: if I typecast (int) '11' it becomes 11

Comment: yes, and i think then is_int should work.

Comment: No, it doesn't, because '11' shall not pass.

Comment: @JarekJakubowski post your code which you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Check for is_string() instead of is_numeric()

Edited:

when you ask for

```
is_numeric($key)
```

check for

```
is_numeric($key) and !is_string($key)
```

Comment: @Jarek Jakubowski perhaps you should post your function that merge your array.

Comment: Sure @JarekJakubowski ?   var_dump(is_string(10)); bool(false)
var_dump(is_string('10')); bool(true)  on PHP 5.4.17

Comment: `$test[]='index1';
$test['100']='assoc';
$test[]='index2';
var_dump(array_keys($test));` all returns int

Comment: @corretge And then: 
`foreach($test as $k => $v)
 var_dump(is_string($v));` all returns true.

Comment: yes @JarekJakubowski , you can't use array_merge() for the same reason. Don't user array_keys, use your own function with the is_numeric() and !is_string() tech

Comment: @corretge your code does not return expected array, however I found the solution and posted above.

Comment: @JarekJakubowski I copy&paste your function and fix only the is_numeric and !is_string issue to differentiate 10 of '10'. I edited my answer to prevent confussions.